# using multiple columns to group by treatment in R

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have 4 different treatment combinations with all of the different variables in different columns. For examples, treatment, drought, genotype, block, date, plant. But I would like to group these within the columns and rows. Since my experimental design is in block effects, I have replicates in each of the multiple blocks. I have used dplyr and subset but I am not sure if I can list multiple things using this. So for a given treatment I would need an example such as this: all the genotype 1 in block 1, with drought and biochar as an effect.

I would need to subset the subset essentially

Comment: This is hard to follow. Please share a small example of input and show the desired output. For example purposes, it is probably enough to consider 2 treatments, 2 drought conditions, and 2 genotypes, and ignore the rest, and we'll keep in mind that the solution needs to scale up. (Or something like that--pick your 3 favorites.)

Comment: this is what i need to filter is having all the data that say drought but also the treatment is biochar, and i want all genotype values                                                                                                                                    
library(dplyr)
BD<-filter(dat,drought=="drought", treatment=="biochar", genotype=="ALL")

Comment: So what's not working with `BD<-filter(dat,drought=="drought", treatment=="biochar", genotype=="ALL")`? That code looks fine. I really do think some sample data and desired output would make things much clearer... could you please put some sample data in the question?

Comment: Similar to what Gregor asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I've figured it out I needed to put an & for the subset I needed                                                                                                  
library(dplyr)
BD<-filter(dat,drought=="drought" & treatment=="biochar")
NBD<-filter(dat,drought=="drought" & treatment=="no biochar")
BND<-filter(dat, drought=="no drought" & treatment=="biochar")
NBND<-filter(dat, drought=="no drought" & treatment=="no biochar")